# Can't find a specific Control using Controls.Find()

Tags: c#, .net

I'm using `Controls.Find()` method to find a `ListBox` that i created dynamically. Name of those `ListBoxes` come from Directories that i created and named uniquely. Everytime i use this method it says the reference is `null`. How do i get the actual `ListBox` that i want?

Here is code:

```
public DosyaTakipAraci()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    string anaDizin = Properties.Settings.Default.anaDizin;

    if (anaDizin == "" || anaDizin == null)
    {
        dizinSecici.Description = "Lütfen dosyalarınızın kaydedileceği bir dizin seçiniz.";
        dizinSecici.ShowDialog();

        Properties.Settings.Default.anaDizin = dizinSecici.SelectedPath + @"\";
        Properties.Settings.Default.Save();

    }

    string[] dizinler = Directory.GetDirectories(anaDizin);

    if (dizinler.Length > 0)
        DizinleriYukle(dizinler);
}
```

> This method loads all Directories

```
private void DizinleriYukle(string[] dizinler)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dizinler.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        DirectoryInfo dizin = new DirectoryInfo(dizinler[i]);
        DizinYukleyici(dizin.Name);
    }
}
```

> This method is belongs to Directory icon that is created for each Directory

```
private void DizinSimge_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    string[] dosyalar = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);

    PictureBox simge = (PictureBox)sender;

    string dizinAdi = simge.Name;
    string anaDizin = Properties.Settings.Default.anaDizin;

    foreach (string dosya in dosyalar)
    {

        string dosyaAdi = Path.GetFileName(dosya);

        if (File.Exists($@"{anaDizin}{dizinAdi}\{dosyaAdi}"))
            return;

        File.Copy(dosya, $@"{anaDizin}{dizinAdi}\{dosyaAdi}", true);

        DosyaYukleyici(Panel.Controls.Find(dizinAdi, true).FirstOrDefault() as ListBox);
    }
}
```

> This method loads the Directory and creates Controls related to the Directory

```
private void DizinYukleyici(string dizinAdi)
{
    #region Kontrol tanımları

    PictureBox dizinSimge = new PictureBox
    {
        Name = dizinAdi,
        Image = Properties.Resources.folder,
        Size = new Size(32, 32),
        Location = new Point(this.X, this.Y),
        AllowDrop = true
    };

    TextBox dizinBaslik = new TextBox
    {
        Name = dizinAdi,
        Text = dizinAdi,
        Location = new Point(this.X + dizinSimge.Width + 5, this.Y + 8),
        Font = new Font("Segou UI", 8.25f),
        BackColor = this.BackColor,
        BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None,
        ReadOnly = true
    };

    ListBox Dosyalar = new ListBox
    {
        Name = dizinAdi,
        Text = null,
        Location = new Point(this.X, this.Y + dizinSimge.Height + 5),
        BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None,
        BackColor = this.BackColor,
        Width = dizinSimge.Width + dizinBaslik.Width + 5
    };

    #endregion

    #region Olaylar
    dizinSimge.DragEnter += new DragEventHandler(DizinSimge_DragEnter);
    dizinSimge.DragDrop += new DragEventHandler(DizinSimge_DragDrop);
    dizinBaslik.DoubleClick += new EventHandler(Baslik_DoubleClick);
    dizinBaslik.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(Baslik_Press);
    Dosyalar.DragEnter += new DragEventHandler(DizinSimge_DragEnter);
    Dosyalar.DragDrop += new DragEventHandler(Dosyalar_DragDrop);
    #endregion            

    Panel.Controls.Add(dizinSimge);
    Panel.Controls.Add(dizinBaslik);
    Panel.Controls.Add(Dosyalar);

    DosyaYukleyici(Dosyalar);

    this.X += (short)(dizinSimge.Width + dizinBaslik.Width + 5);
}
```

> This method Loads files of a Directory and adds them to related ListBox

```
private void DosyaYukleyici(ListBox Liste)
{
    string dizinAdi = Liste.Name;
    Liste.Items.Clear();

    string anaDizin = Properties.Settings.Default.anaDizin;
    string dizin = Path.Combine(anaDizin, dizinAdi);

    string[] dosyalar = Directory.GetFiles(dizin);

    foreach (string dosya in dosyalar)
    {
        Liste.Items.Add(Path.GetFileName(dosya));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You give the `PictureBox`, the `TextBox` and the `ListBox` the same name `dizinAdi`. Now when you search a `ListBox`, you may find a `PictureBox` or a `TextBox` first. Then you try to cast it with  `as ListBox` which yields `null` if it is not the `ListBox`.

Filter the by type:

```
Panel.Controls.Find(dizinAdi, true).OfType<ListBox>().FirstOrDefault()
```

alternatively, you could give different names to different controls like

```
"lst" + dizinAdi
"txt" + dizinAdi
"pic" + dizinAdi
```

or

```
dizinAdi + "ListBox"
dizinAdi + "TextBox"
dizinAdi + "PictureBox"
```